# GRASS GIS - V.VOL.IDW interpolation interpolates same property vertically

Tags: grass-gis, 3d

When interpolating a 3D raster using `v.vol.idw` ([ref](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/v.vol.idw.html)), the vertical cross section show that the properties are the same vertically.

```
v.vol.idw input=GEOMOD_March24@Toronto output=April12_Res200x2_24interpolPts column=Texture_mm npoints=24
```

I am using 24 points as the number of interpolation, and I am wondering if that is too small which results in this continuous.

Comment: This will highly depend on your 3D points and their distribution. Hard to say like this... Maybe https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.univar.html can help here.

Comment: Here are the results of running                                                                     
 v.univar map=GEOMOD_March24@Toronto column=Texture_mm                           
number of features with non NULL attribute: 316959
number of missing attributes: 0
number of NULL attributes: 0
minimum: 0
maximum: 300
range: 300
sum: 330440
mean: 1.04253

Comment: mean of absolute values: 1.04253
population standard deviation: 6.7796
population variance: 45.963
population coefficient of variation: 6.503
sample standard deviation: 6.77961
sample variance: 45.9631
kurtosis: 1182.54
skewness: 29.4649

Comment: Use this link for a screenshot of a cross section of IDW interpolation 
  https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/7057/na5QUG.png     here is a screenshot using v.vol.rst for the same data and location.    https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/7742/5f5RDH.png